# Dart Json nested object parsing failure

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I've got json file with some nested objects inside subs in it:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "data": [{
    "married": true,
    "subs":[
      {
        "name":{
          "sub1":{}
        **},**
      },
    ]
  },
]}
```

If I add another 'name' object (with comma as separator), jsonDecode returns nothing.
if there goes single object, without comma - it's ok.

My Json structure is correct, and it's not restricted to use nested objects at all. Please anyone help.

Comment: It is difficult to help without the complete JSON that is failing, code, etc.

Comment: what does the ** ** means??

Answer (score 0):

This line has problem `**},**` and if changed to `},` the problem will be solved..
you can check your json by online tools (e.g https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#)